# JavaScript: How to change the regular expression to accept (),-.;[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an existing regular expression which accepts the Simplified Chinese characters.

```js
public chinaValidator: any = '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$';
```

But I want to modify this to accept the below also

```
(    Left parenthesis    U+0028
)    Right parenthesis    U+0029
,    Comma    U+002C
-    Minus    U+002D
.    Full stop    U+002E
;    Semicolon    U+003B
[    Left bracket    U+005B
]    Right bracket    U+005D
```

Can any one help me form the regular expression for this?
Note it can accept either '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$'; or with those characters

Comment: Just add these characters to your subset: `'^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[]+$'` Remember to escape the reserved characters with a preceeding backslash

Comment: Hi need    ] Right bracket    U+005D also

Comment: Then just add`\]` into your character subset.

Comment: '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[\]+$' is this correct

Comment: No, because you did not escape the `[]` characters. Use this: `'^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[\]]+$'`

Comment: one more issue it is not accepting spaces

Comment: i want regex to accept space also

Comment: Hi Terry the regex should accept either this '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[]+$' or that '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$'; but it is not accepting only this without those characters

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a few characters to your subset.

The complete regular expression would be:

```
^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[\] ]+$
```

Explanation

```
^ matches the start the of string
[ is the start of the character class
\u4E00-\u9FCC matches Chinese characters
\( matches a left parenthesis
\) matches a right parenthesis
, matches a comma
\- matches a hyphen
\. matches a dot
; matches a semicolon
\[ matches a left square bracket
\] matches a right square bracket
  (whitespace) matches a space
] is the end of the character class
+ matches the character class one or more times
$ matches the end of the string
```

Comment: does this allow space also . i want to allow space

Comment: @nickolas I edited the answer to include that. Could you click the grey check mark next to the answer to accept it? It might help future users, and gives you reputation.

Comment: sure i am testing my code using the expression you provided jus a min sir

Comment: i want my regular expression to accept either this  '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$'; or the combination of the characters i mentioned . the one you wrote does not accept plain characters without the symbols

Comment: Hi the regex should accept either this '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC\(\),\-\.;\[]+$' or that '^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$'; but it is not accepting only this without those characters

Comment: @nickolas I don't know what you mean. It works fine - https://regex101.com/r/Aebl8l/2 (the pieces of text that are highlighted in blue are matches)

Comment: @nickolas From your question, I see that you are storing it in a string. If you use a string, you need to use `new RegExp('regex string', 'modifiers')`